# Is it necessary to define relationships in Ms access?

Tags: database, ms-access

I develop Access Databases.
All access databases use an ODBC DSN file link to a MS SQL Server and a postgres server once development is complete.

Many times I will run queries on the front end, but occasionally I will make back end queries to make the servers do the hard work.

I am wondering if it is necessary to create relationships in the Database Tools tab in the ribbon. I know it makes developing easier from time to time when using the query design dialogue and I know any MS Access computer class will teach you to make them, but aside from that what is the point? Does it speed up queries? Is it a convention/etiquette thing like commenting your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your tables in an ODBC backend, the only direct reason to define relationships in the Access frontend is the convenience to have JOINs predefined in the query designer.

In a large-ish application, that's reason enough for me.

And of course, it will help anyone else who will develop in the frontend to understand the table relations.

BTW, why do you develop with SQL Server when PostgreSql will be the production database? Don't underestimate the differences between the SQL dialects (since you also use backend queries and maybe stored procedures).

Comment: From time to time we will need to create views using pg admin. That view is then treated like a linked table and the server can do all the hard work and access can simple display. I like your answer above. It makes good enough sense to me

Comment: I would add that it allows the forcing of referential integrity as well.

Comment: @random_answer_guy: With linked ODBC tables, you can't enforce or even specify referential integrity in the frontend - this will have to be done in the backend database server.

Comment: @Andre Yes I understand that, was just listing the benefits of defining the relationships, as it is one. Also he didn't specifically state that all of his tables are linked.